# Array expression vs explicit loop in parallel and serial

Tags: fortran, openmp, gfortran

I tried to OpenMP parallelize the following minimal example and compare array expressions with explicit but am surprised, that I get no speedup.
Could you explain to me the problem?

```
program time_routines
  use iso_fortran_env, only: real64, int64
  USE OMP_LIB
  integer, parameter :: wp = real64
  integer(kind=int64) :: start, finish, rate
  integer, parameter :: problem_size = 2 * 10**4
  integer :: i
  real(wp), allocatable :: X(:, :), Y(:, :)

  allocate(X(problem_size, problem_size), Y(problem_size, problem_size))

  call random_number(X)
  call system_clock(count_rate=rate)

  !$omp parallel
    write(6, *) "Hello from thread: ", OMP_GET_THREAD_NUM()
  !$OMP END PARALLEL

  ! fill cache lines
  Y = 2._wp * X + 3._wp

  call system_clock(start)
    Y = 2._wp * X + 3._wp
  call system_clock(finish)
  write(6, *) 'serial array expression'
  write(6, *) 'Elapsed Time in seconds:', real(finish - start, kind=wp) / real(rate, kind=wp)

  call system_clock(start)
  !$omp workshare
    Y = 2._wp * X + 3._wp
  !$omp end workshare
  call system_clock(finish)
  write(6, *) 'parallel array expression'
  write(6, *) 'Elapsed Time in seconds:', real(finish - start, kind=wp) / real(rate, kind=wp)



  call system_clock(start)
    do j = 1, size(X, 2)
      do i = 1, size(X, 1)
        Y(i, j) = 2._wp * X(i, j) + 3._wp
      end do
    end do
  call system_clock(finish)
  write(6, *) 'Explicit serial loop'
  write(6, *) 'Elapsed Time in seconds:', real(finish - start, kind=wp) / real(rate, kind=wp)

  call system_clock(start)
  !$omp do
    do j = 1, size(X, 2)
      do i = 1, size(X, 1)
        Y(i, j) = 2._wp * X(i, j) + 3._wp
      end do
    end do
  !$omp end do
  call system_clock(finish)
  write(6, *) 'Explicit parallel loop'
  write(6, *) 'Elapsed Time in seconds:', real(finish - start, kind=wp) / real(rate, kind=wp)

end program
```

If I compile with
`gfortran -fopenmp -O2 -Wall openmp_basics.f90 -o test.exe && ./test.exe` my timings are the same for all possible ways of executing the calculation.

Comment: `!$ omp do` isn't `!$omp parallel do` - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31832676/omp-what-is-the-difference-between-omp-parallel-do-and-omp-do-without-parallel

Comment: Also, `!$omp workshare` isn't `!$omp parallel workshare`. Note that some compilers do not really generate parallel code for the `workshare` construct.

Comment: Depending on the version of gfortran  that you have, the options "-fopt-info -march=native -mtune=native -ftree-vectorize -funroll-loops" may be of interest.

Comment: Besides what is said above, vectorization with an appropriate limit for unroll-loops may allow a single thread to take nearly all of the bandwidth of a single CPU single memory controller platform.If the problem is large enough, non-temporal stores could be more advantageous than multiple threads.  There isn't significant computational work beyond a simple copy, as a plain parallel fma would do it all.

Comment: You also get the same performance for array-operations and explicit loops. This is normal. The compiler gets basically the same information. Array syntax is more about convenience/clarity than performance. Some intrinsic functions (like `matmul`) may be faster than explicit loops, but usually not much so when optimization is applied.

Comment: @JonatanÖström Actually I expected the same or better performance for array-operations. I basically wrote this MWE to measure and prove it to someone who strongly believes that one has to write Fortran77 loops to get full speed.

Comment: @mcocdawc yeah I see. If one Googles for the BLAS source code and end up in netlib, one can get the impression that this is how fast code should look. However, that is the reference implementation that define the functionality that other implementations should be equivalent to. It just looks like that because it's old and explicit for clarity. If you would look at the source code of MKL's BLAS or openBLAS you will se a lot of hand written assembly code for the critical operations. I also also have a vague memory that openBLAS is currently written mainly in C.